# Symfony 3.4 LTS, PostgreSQL 10, DoctrineDBAL could not find driver

Tags: postgresql, symfony, symfony-3.4

I use MAMP server with PHP 7.1.5; Symfony Framework 3.4.2, PostgreSQL 10 for a new project. I also use PostGIS to store space data with geometry data type in PostgreSQL. Therefore I installed and used: "jsor/doctrine-postgis": "^1.5"

Following is part of my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "jsor/doctrine-postgis": "^1.5",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
```

The parameters.yml:

```
server_ver: 10.0
database_driver: pdo_pgsql
database_host: localhost
database_port: 5432
database_name: qtqg
database_path:     ~
database_user: postgres
database_password: admin
```

The config.yml:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        default:
            mapping_types:
                _text: string
            server_version: %server_ver%
            driver:   %database_driver%
            host:     %database_host%
            port:     %database_port%
            dbname:   %database_name%
            path:     %database_path%
            user:     %database_user%
            password: %database_password%
            persistent: true
            charset:  UTF8
            logging: %kernel.debug%
            profiling: %kernel.debug%

    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
    #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
    #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
    #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
    #   3. Uncomment next line:
    #path: '%database_path%'
    types:
        geography:
            class: 'Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Types\GeographyType'
            commented: false
        geometry:
            class: 'Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Types\GeometryType'
            commented: false
        raster:
            class: 'Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Types\RasterType'
            commented: false
```

Everything work well, I can use cmd to generate Entity:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle annotation
```

And after that generate CRUD:

```
php bin/console generate:doctrine:crud AppBundleMonitoringAdminBundle:coquan -n --format=annotation --with-write
```

The Running PHP is PHP 7.1.5 and I also checked php.ini file in C:\Windows and loaded php.ini in MAMP server. `php -m` command shows:

```
PDO
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
```

I don't think any problem with data driver because it can connect and generate Entities, CRUD....
But after generate CRUD and try to access the controller to list all item in one Entity, I got the Error:

```
An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver
```

One of the error line is:

```
AbstractPostgreSQLDriver->convertException('An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver', object(PDOException)) in vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException.php (line 176)
```

I tried many way including changing mamp to xamp, wamp server, all recommendation about how to config dbal... but the error is still there

Could anyone help me!

Comment: Looks like you have `pdo_pgsql` enabled in CLI, but not on your web server. You can use phpinfo() to check enabled extensions and check which  php.ini is in use.

Comment: How could I enable it in web server; php -v showed it is php 7.15(cli); php --ini show 2 php.ini files, one in C:/windows and loaded one in c:/mamp/bin/php/php7.15 but I copied so these two files are the same

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with PostgreSQL 10

Inside `vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/PostgreSqlSchemaManager.php` line line 292 change

```
$data = $this->_conn->fetchAll('SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM ' . $this->_platform->quoteIdentifier($sequenceName));
```

For

```
$version = floatval($this->_conn->getWrappedConnection()->getServerVersion());

if ($version >= 10) {
   $data = $this->_conn->fetchAll('SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM pg_sequences WHERE schemaname = \'public\' AND sequencename = '.$this->_conn->quote($sequenceName));
}
else
{
    $data = $this->_conn->fetchAll('SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM ' . $this->_platform->quoteIdentifier($sequenceName));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was have the same issue with postgres 9.6.4 with WAMP on windows 10

`phpinfo()` would display `pdo_pgsql` as loaded, and it worked fine in another PHP application.  `php -m` from the gitbash would not show `pdo_pgsql`

In the end, I had to edit the php.ini that was loaded and uncomment these 2 lines

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

restart apache and now it works!!!!